# PC crashes on building a VS2008 WPF application

Tags: windows-xp, .net-3.5

My PC crashes and restarts whenever i build a WPF application on my VS2008.

I have no idea why this happens and i have collected the EventViewer logs for reference.

One interesting thing to note is that the event source is from the **.NET Runtime version 
2.0.50727.3625**  for a WPF application.

I'm planning to re-install my .NET Framework, before that i would like to know if you guys

can give me any inputs. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1022
Date:       12/22/2011
Time:       2:13:30 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   BMH303408
Description:
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3625 - Profiling flag set, but required environment (COR_PROFILER) was not set.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.



Event Type: Error
Event Source:   crypt32
Event Category: None
Event ID:   8
Date:       12/22/2011
Time:       2:12:47 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   BMH303408
Description:
Failed auto update retrieval of third-party root list sequence number from: <http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootseq.txt> with error: The server name or address could not be resolved


For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.



For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.


Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Schannel
Event Category: None
Event ID:   36870
Date:       12/22/2011
Time:       2:12:35 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   BMH303408
Description:
A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x80090016.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.



Event Type: Error
Event Source:   System Error
Event Category: (102)
Event ID:   1003
Date:       12/22/2011
Time:       2:14:01 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   BMH303408
Description:
Error code 1000007f, parameter1 00000008, parameter2 80042000, parameter3 00000000, parameter4 00000000.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 53 79 73 74 65 6d 20 45   System E
0008: 72 72 6f 72 20 20 45 72   rror  Er
0010: 72 6f 72 20 63 6f 64 65   ror code
0018: 20 31 30 30 30 30 30 37    1000007
0020: 66 20 20 50 61 72 61 6d   f  Param
0028: 65 74 65 72 73 20 30 30   eters 00
0030: 30 30 30 30 30 38 2c 20   000008, 
0038: 38 30 30 34 32 30 30 30   80042000
0040: 2c 20 30 30 30 30 30 30   , 000000
0048: 30 30 2c 20 30 30 30 30   00, 0000
0050: 30 30 30 30               0000
```